# Spring WS - Looking for Request header/payload and Response header/payload Example

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws, webservicetemplate

I am required to develop Web Service using the Spring Framework.
Scenario is like this:

My program will send a SOAP request (header + payload) to a service and expects a response (header + payload) back from the service.
Both the payload and header are important and needed by the program.

Problem is that I am unable to find any example in Spring WS where both header and payload are sent as part of request and header and payload extracted from response.

I am using `WebServiceGatewaySupport` and `WebServiceTemplate` for sending of request and fetching of response.

`WebServiceTemplate` provides 2 methods for sending request:

- `marshalSendAndReceive`
- `sendAndReceive`

Problem with `marshalSendAndReceive` is that I will not get back the response header though I can send the request header.

Problem with `sendAndReceive` is that I will not be able to send the request header though I will be able to extract the response header.

The only solution currently available right now is to use Interceptors but it seems that this is not the proper way of handling the headers as header is intercepted before it reaches the calling function. To have the calling function access to response header, we will need to make the Interceptor as stateful which is not desirable.

I will really appreciate guidance and help from anyone who can provide me with an example of how to properly achieve this.

Please find my code below when using sendAndReceive:

```
public class ClientAccountInformation extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    public ClientAccountInformation() {
    }

    public FIGetAcctsInfoCallBackRs sendRequest(GetAcctInfoRq request, HeaderRq headerRq) {

        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate =  getWebServiceTemplate();
        try {
            ResponseAndHeader responseAndHeader = webServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(Constants.WEBSERVICE_URL, 
                new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
                  public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException {
                      try {
                          Jaxb2Marshaller marshallerRq = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
                          marshallerRq.setContextPath("com.abc.domain..getacctinfo");

                          marshallerRq.afterPropertiesSet();

                          MarshallingUtils.marshal(marshallerRq, request, message);

                          SoapHeader soapHeader = ((SoapMessage)message).getSoapHeader();
                          JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(HeaderRq.class);
                          Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
                          marshaller.marshal(HeaderRq, soapHeader.getResult());
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                  }
                },
                new WebServiceMessageExtractor<ResponseAndHeader>() {
                  public ResponseAndHeader extractData(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException {
                    SoapHeader header = ((SoapMessage)message).getSoapHeader();
                    Iterator<SoapHeaderElement> it = header.examineHeaderElements(new QName("urn:test", "HeaderRs"));
                    return new ResponseAndHeader(
                        it.hasNext() ? (HeaderRs)jaxb2Marshaller().unmarshal(it.next().getSource())
                                     : null,
                        (GetAcctInfoRs) MarshallingUtils.unmarshal(jaxb2Marshaller(), message));
                  }
                });

            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        jaxb2Marshaller.setContextPath("com.abc.domain.getacctinfo");

        return jaxb2Marshaller;
    }
}
```

The above code always returns null for the response header.

Comment: @M. Deinum There is no assistance on the question. What can I do to possibly get assistance on this.

Comment: Maybe add the code you wrote with `marshalSendAndReceive` and `sendAndReceive`? Probably somebody will be able to show how to combine both to achieve what you want.

Comment: Hi @AndreasVeithen, I have attached the sample code where I am using the sendAndReceive function but the response header is always null.

Comment: Have you checked that the response actually has a header with that name?

Comment: Hi @AndreasVeithen. I have solved the issue, thanks to you blog post. I have posted my response below as the correct answer. If you have time, please have a look and provide your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue. I can send the SOAP header to a service and extract the response header from response also. No need for interceptors.

Main help was from blog post from Andreas Veithen. Thanks.

```
public class ClientSamaAccountInformation extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    public ClientSamaAccountInformation() {
    }

    public FIGetAcctsInfoCallBackRs sendRequest(FIGetAcctsInfoCallBackRq request, MsgHdrRq msgHdrRq) {

        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate =  getWebServiceTemplate();
        try {
            ResponseAndHeader responseAndHeader = webServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(Constants.WEBSERVICE_URL, 
                new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
                  public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException {
                      try {
                          Jaxb2Marshaller marshallerRq = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
                          marshallerRq.setContextPath("com.abc.domain..getacctinfo");

                          marshallerRq.afterPropertiesSet();

                          MarshallingUtils.marshal(marshallerRq, request, message);

                          SoapHeader soapHeader = ((SoapMessage)message).getSoapHeader();
                          JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MsgHdrRq.class);
                          Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
                          marshaller.marshal(msgHdrRq, soapHeader.getResult());
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                  }
                },
                new WebServiceMessageExtractor<ResponseAndHeader>() {
                  public ResponseAndHeader extractData(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException {

                    //Extract response payload
                    FIGetAcctsInfoCallBackRs response = null;
                    try {
                        Jaxb2Marshaller marshallerRs = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
                        marshallerRs.setContextPath("com.abc.domain..getacctinfo");
                        marshallerRs.afterPropertiesSet();
                        response = (FIGetAcctsInfoCallBackRs) MarshallingUtils.unmarshal(marshallerRs, message);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //Extract response header
                    MsgHdrRs msgHdrRs = null;
                    try {
                        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MsgHdrRs.class);
                        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

                        SoapHeader header = ((SoapMessage)message).getSoapHeader();
                        Iterator<SoapHeaderElement> it = header.examineHeaderElements(new QName("http://www.abc.def.com/common/Header", "MsgHdrRs"));
                        while(it.hasNext()) {
                            msgHdrRs = (MsgHdrRs) unmarshaller.unmarshal(it.next().getSource());
                            System.out.println(msgHdrRs);

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
                  }
                });

            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```